# Find URLs in .NET?

Tags: .net, url, string-parsing

Given a list of strings, I'm interested in finding which ones are valid `http://` URLs. My first approach would be to use a regex and do something like this:

`var urls = strs.Where(str => urlRegex.matches(str));`

Is there a more idiomatic/natural/simple way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the parsing built in to the [System.Uri Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) to validate the Urls.  This has the benefit of correctly handling query strings included with the Url, and should be able to parse any string that .Net can use as a Url.

After using TryCreate to attempt parsing each string, check that the Uti.Scheme property is an HTTP uri (otherwise a filesystem path would also pass the filter).

Answer (score 1):

Yes I would use [Uri.TryCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131572.aspx) and then test the Scheme property of successfully parsed URI's to ensure it is HTTP.

However, if the URI's you were looking for are substrings of a larger block of text, regex is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the regex based approach and your approach looks fine to me